# Get Custom Product attribute using camel case

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, magic-getter

How can i get custom product attribute `custom_attribute_1` using `$product->getCustomAttribute1` .Is camel casing works for numbers?

Comment: use $_product->getData($attributeCode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does **not** work:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute1()
```

This does work:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute_1()
$product->getData('custom_attribute_1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If camel case won't working, you should try with

> ->getData('attribute')

Answer (score 0):

Use `$product->getCustomAttribute_1()` for getting `custom_attribute_1` value